# Java - Select from a set of types of an object

Tags: java

This is more of a theoretical question. I'm not sure how to approach a problem I've trying to overcome with Java.

There is a Car class and the company only makes 10 car models. A buyer wants a car and says what they are looking for. The software goes out and finds them the perfect car. [This isn't the actually problem, but it should make more sense this way]

What is the best way to do this?

My ideas:

1) ArrayList populated with car models and then the program searches through it looking for the perfect car. If it finds it, then it duplicates the Car for the buyer

2) In the Car class constructor, look at user parameters and build a Car that solves the user's preferences.

What would you recommend?

Comment: Each car should implement a interface, and then create a function (`getCarForSpecs(int horsePower, String color, etc`) that returns a class of this interface type, and have that function do some logic to determine what the best car is based on specs.

Comment: This maybe sounds like an Abstract Factory pattern here. Are you having models for each of the 10 types?